# Совершенный vs. несовершенный вид

Tags: синтаксис, аспектология

В моем языке нет такого феномена как аспект, поэтому трудно понять аспектуальный нюанс.

**1.** Возьмем условно-уступительные конструкции с сослагательным наклонением:

> **Кто бы ни поехал в Лондон**, больше оттуда не возвращается.

Я читала, что такие конструкции обозначают не единичные, а повторные действия. Не совсем понимаю, почему в примере используется совершенный вид (*поехал*), если речь о повторяющемся событии. 
(мое предположение, что в предложении акцент делается на завершености действия, каждого отдельного действия, но я не уверена)

**2**. В чем была бы разница между:

> (a) **Кто ни едет в Лондон**, больше оттуда не возвращается.
>
> (b) **Кто бы ни поехал в Лондон**, больше оттуда не возвращается.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Сложность в том, что значения видов глаголов тоже возможно смешивать как и всякие простые значения слов и выражений русского языка. Поэтому РЯ и могучий.

кто бы ни ехал - делал попытку, ехал, но не факт, что доехал... Это несовершенный вид

кто бы ни поехал - съездил всё-таки, получилось попасть... Это совершенный вид

Для вашего вопроса, точнее передает значение: "кто бы ни поехал..."

Выражение умышленно подогнано под привлекательность Лондона. Расчёт, на превосходство. Это достигается путём смешения приставок в глаголе (то есть выбран глагол в смысле другого глагола). Ведь точнее употребить вместо "поехал" слово "уехал", но тут привлекательность с превосходством выражаются уже не так ярко.

Answer (score 0):

Просто как носитель языка, а не вижу тут никаких повторных действий. Поехал **один раз** - и не вернулся. Поехал имеет смысл "отправился в поездку", ехал - "находился в поездке".
Ваша пара примеров должна превратиться в две пары:

1а. Кто ни едет в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.

1б. Кто бы ни ехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.

2а. Кто ни поедет в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.

2б. Кто бы ни поехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.

2б звучит нормально, остальные - вроде и правильно, но не на слуху. Во-первых, логичнее говорить о тех, кто "отправился в поездку". Во-вторых, возможно, причина в том, что на слух трудно отличить "ни" от "не", и сослагательное "бы" устраняет всякую неоднозначность при восприятии на слух.

Comment: cпасибо за ответ! я имела ввиду повторeниe деиствия в таких конструкциях как "сколько бы он ни открывал книгу, все равно не мог выучить правило" (=возвращался к открытию книги неоднократно). или я неправильно думаю? Вы как носитель смогли бы сказать это предложение с совершенным видом? "сколько бы он ни открыл книгу, все равно не мог выучить правило". Если Ваш ответ "нет", как можно объяснить использование совершенного вида в "Кто бы ни поехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается." и использование несов. вида в "сколько бы он ни открывал книгу, все равно не мог выучить правило"?

Comment: Мой ответ "нет", а на все остальное, думаю, @behemothus дал блестящий ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Понимаете, какая штука, повторяемость события существенна только для настоящего времени. Сравните в английском - перфект настоящего (обычного и продолженного) времени с перфектом прошедшего. Первый - вполне употребимая форма, второй - уже требует какого-то необычного контекста. В русском примерно то же самое в отношении посторяемости действия.

> Кто бы ни поехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.

Строго говоря, здесь нет повторяющегося события. Здесь имеется в виду что каждый только один раз ехал/ездил/поехал в Лондон. Для повторяющегося события необходим чтобы один семантический агенс выполнял это действие. 
Вообще это правило о повторяющемся действии хорошо работает только в настоящем времени (да и то надо оговаривать ситуацию с т. н. "глаголами движения", для которых существует самостоятельное слово, выражающее повторность). В прошедшем времени, тем более - в сослагательном наклонении, правило уже не такое четкое. Скажем, "я рисовал" может означать и однократное действие и повторное, без контекста сказать нельзя.

В вашем же примере и глагол движения (пара ехать - ездить вообще супплетивная), и наклонение - сослагательное. В результате имеем семантически близкие, почти неразличимые возможности

***Кто бы ни поехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.  (1)

Кто бы ни ехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.  (2)

Кто бы ни ездил в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается. (3)

Кто бы ни съездил в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается. (4)***

Все варианты допустимы, все означают одно и то же, выбор определяется более традицией и стилистикой, чем смыслом. Вариант (1) пожалуй, наиболее частый, хотя грамматические менее понятный, вы, видимо, это и отметили. Логичнее сказать (2), ибо результат такой поездки сам по себе не важен, но он менее употребим.

> ```
> (a) Кто ни едет в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.
>
> (b) Кто бы ни поехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.
> ```

У меня это номера (1) и (2). Разницы существенной нету.
Между (1) и (2) можно усмотреть различие, что (1) констатирует факт на данный момент, а (2) - прогнозирует на будущее, но это не грамматическое различие, скорее восприятие.

В общем это момент тонкий, я думаю, вам не стоит сейчас заморачиваться, употребляйте в подобных конструкциях совершенный вид - не ошибетесь.
Вот в настоящем временем - там да, надо строго следовать правилу. Когда и если прочувуствуете, будет проще перенести и на остальные времена и наклонения.

А вообще если хотите разобраться с аспектом (видом) на теоретическом уровне, вот попалась статья по сравнительного анализу категории вида.
http://www.lingling.ru/sschool/book_2009_2011/Arkadjev_2010.pdf

Я пробежался "наискосок", не могу ручаться, что там всё правильно, но на первый взгляд - очень неплохо изложено.

Answer (score 0):

**Обе формы** (изъявительного и сослагательного наклонения) передают одно и **то же содержание**, но строятся они по-разному.

1) **Кто ни едет (поедет, отправится) в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.** Это изъявительное наклонение, глагол в настоящем времени. Придаточное уступительное со значением обобщения.

Если взять глагол в прошедшем времени, то мы получим значение **уступки (=хотя),  а не обобщенности**, например: **Сколько не ездил в Лондон, всегда узнавал что-то новое.**  А вот вариант без частицы БЫ  "Кто  ни поехал в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается"  – это, скорее всего, неверная грамматика, содержание сообщения не воспринимается на слух.

2) **Кто бы ни поехал (отправился) в Лондон, больше оттуда не возвращается.** Это сослагательное наклонение со значением **обобщенности действия**, то есть **все так делают**. Здесь используется форма прошедшего времени, но она **не имеет значения прошедшего времени**: форма прош. время + частица БЫ – это **форма сослагательного наклонения**.

В этом случае нужна **завершенность действия (совершенный вид глагола)**, событие состоит в следующем: поехал и не вернулся. Так поступают все, поэтому повторяемость/обобщенность относится к явлению, а не к каждому частному (завершенному) случаю.